# How to define a starting point in the condition?

Tags: java, modulo

**The problem:**

I want all numbers from 1-50 that are not divisible by 7, but also don't have a 7 in them, like 17,27,etc. The code below works but `(i-10)%7` has to start from `i=6`. Now it thinks the number 3 doesn't count cause `(3-10)=-7` that is 0 mod 7. how do i solve this in the if statement?

```
for(int i=1; i<=50;i++){
    if(i%7!=0 &&  (i-10)%7!=0){
        System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second condition is wrong. 27 ends in 7, but (27-10)%7!=0.

You just need to check that i % 10 is not 7.

```
if(i%7!=0 && i%10!=7)
```

Comment: yes, thats a solution thx. But is it possible to make a condition such that i is checked starting from 6?

Comment: it checks from 6 onwards doesn't includes 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: @mr_ecko You can start the loop from 6 by writing - `for(int i=6; i<=50;i++){`

Comment: Yes also a good solution thx very much. But is it possible to do something like that in the if statement. Just a educational question. the problem is solved i was just wondering if it was possible.

Comment: @mr_ecko But shouldn't the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 be printed? They are not divisible by 7 and don't have 7 in them. You can change the condition to accept only integers starting at 6 if you want - `if(i>=6 && i%7!=0 && i%10!=7)`.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick

```
for(int i=1; i<=50;i++){
        if(i==7 || i==3)
        {
            if(i==3)
                System.out.println(i);              
        }
        else if(i%7!=0 &&  (i%10)%7!=0){
            System.out.println(i);}
    }
```

***output is...***

### 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 11 12 13 15 16 18 19 22 23 24 25 26 29 31 32 33 34 36 38 39 41 43 44 45 46 48

***UPDATE***

If you want your if condition to start checking from `i=6` then you can do this...

```
for(int i=1; i<=50;i++){            
            if(i>=6 && i%7!=0 &&  (i%10)%7!=0)
            System.out.println(i);          
    }
```

but **the output will change to**...

**6 8 9 11 12 13 15 16 18 19 22 23 24 25 26 29 31 32 33 34 36 38 39 41 43 44 45 46 48**

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Casting it to a string and just checking if it contains the string "7".

```
if(i % 7 != 0 && ((String)i).contains("7"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Its seems to basic:

find if the number has 7 or not : number%10==7
find if the number is divisible by 7 or not : number%7==0

combine both in Or clause
if (number%10==7||number%7==0)
do watever.......

but it only applicable if the number<50

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking if each number contains a 7 instead of '(i-10)%7!=0' I would recommend casting i to a string (i + "") and then checking if it contains the char 7

using only i%10 !=7 will only check to see if the last digit is not 7.